# Bayes Theorem for Baum-Welch algorithm

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, baum-welch

I've been reading the Baum-Welch algorithm and somewhere it mentioned this statistical property:
$$
P(X \mid Y,Z) =\frac{ P(X,Y \mid Z)}{P(Y \mid Z)}
$$ 
being based on Bayes' Theorem.
I do understand the basic Bayes' Theorem, which is, 
$$
P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(B \mid A)P(A)}{P(B)},
$$
 but I can't seem to figure out $P(X \mid Y,Z) =\frac{ P(X,Y \mid Z)}{P(Y \mid Z)}$.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a conditional probability is

$$
\mathbb P( A \mid B) = \frac{\mathbb P(A , B) }{\mathbb P(B) }
$$

From that, for three events $X,Y$ and $Z$, we have:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P( X \mid Y,Z ) = \frac{\mathbb P(X, Y,Z)}{\mathbb P(Y,Z)} \qquad (*)
\end{align}
Morevoer,
$$
\mathbb P(X,Y \mid Z) = \frac{\mathbb P(X, Y,Z)}{\mathbb P(Z)}
$$
thus,
$$
\mathbb P(X, Y,Z) = \mathbb P(X,Y \mid Z)  \mathbb P(Z).
$$
If we use this equality in $(*)$ we get,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(X \mid Y, Z)  &= \frac{ \mathbb P(X,Y \mid Z)  \mathbb P(Z)}{\mathbb P(Y,Z)} \\
&= \frac{ \mathbb P(X,Y \mid Z) }{\mathbb P(Y \mid Z)}.
\end{align*}
The last line comes from the fact that
$$
\frac{\mathbb P(Z)}{\mathbb P(Y,Z)} = \frac{1}{\mathbb P(Y \mid Z)}
$$
So finally,

$$
\mathbb P(X \mid Y, Z)  = \frac{ \mathbb P(X,Y \mid Z) }{\mathbb P(Y \mid Z)}.
$$